# Why are changes not recognized when focus leaves control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I use a binding source to bind the class to a form's controls. I'm using WinForms.

When I enter some text in a textbox and click on the Save button (I don't leave the textbox), the property bound to the textbox doesn't get updated.

Is this normal behavior? And if yes, is there a way to accept all changes?

Comment: If you click the Button it gains focus and the textbox looses it, forcing a binding Update. ???

Comment: If I don't explicitly leave the textbox with TAB, the property is not updated.

Comment: I came to know today that you can bind properties in winforms too

Comment: Is `CausesValidation` on the save button set to true? That should be enough. Otherwise you could try `yourbindingsource.EndEdit();` before saving

Comment: Set binding DataSourceUpdateMode like binding.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;

Comment: @Me.Name EndEdit() does the trick.